# Excel: If I open two windows on the same workbook, why do macros stop working in the first window?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to set up a button in Excel to show a dual view of two separate worksheets at the same time.  This is the code I've written so far (see below).  So far the code seems to work.  The problem is that the top window has some activex controls on the worksheet, and they seem to stop working until the bottom window is closed again.  Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?  Thanks.

```
Private Sub DualViewButton_Click()
  Dim windowToPutOnTimeline As Window

  If Windows.Count = 1 Then
    ThisWorkbook.NewWindow
    Windows.Arrange xlArrangeStyleHorizontal, True, False, False
    Set windowToPutOnTimeline = Windows(1)
    If Windows(1).Top < Windows(2).Top Then
      Set windowToPutOnTimeline = Windows(2)
    End If

    With windowToPutOnTimeline
      .Activate
      HorizontalTimelineSheet.Activate
      .DisplayGridlines = False
      .DisplayRuler = False
      .DisplayHeadings = False
      .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
      '.EnableResize = False
    End With

    Windows(2).Activate 'go back to the right focus the user expects.

  Else
    If Windows(1).Top = Windows(2).Top Then
      Windows.Arrange xlArrangeStyleHorizontal, True, False, False
    Else
      Windows.Arrange xlArrangeStyleVertical, True, False, False
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: if I switch the window that's being assigned to windowToPutOnTimeline then the problem goes away.  So I've essentially worked around the problem without knowing why it works the other way.  (see code snippet below)

```
With ThisWorkbook
  Set windowToPutOnTimeline = .Windows(1)
  Set windowToPutOnDataSheet = .Windows(2)
  tmp = .Windows(1).Top
  .Windows(1).Top = .Windows(2).Top
  .Windows(2).Top = tmp
End With
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue you describe, but don't quite understand your workaround. I'd very much appreciate if you could clarify a bit as it would save me from certain doom!

Comment: @Sam, it's been a long time and another job since I worked on that code... but as far as I can recall I was creating two windows to view two different sheets in the same workbook, and I ended up switching which window showed the new worksheet.  I think there may still have been bugs, but in my case they were acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is a bug in ActiveX control.

As a work around, use a button from the Forms Controls, rather than an ActiveX button

Using the Forms button you will need to add a Module, declare a Sub with your code and assign the Sub as the action macro to your button  (as apposed to putting your code in the click event of an ActiveX button)

I tried this on Excel 2007, seem to work OK - the button appears and works on both windows

Comment: Unless you need mousemove events, in which case does not work around.